# trim string value in a multitrigger without a converter?

Tags: wpf, xaml, multidatatrigger

I have a `MultiTrigger` that I use to color the values of my `DataGrid` control. This trigger was working fine until recently when I discovered the color no longer worked. I looked at the database and discovered that blank spaces were trailing my value and thus my trigger comparison of the value would always fail.

I was wondering if there is a stringformat or a trim function that I can do inline with my xaml so that I don't have to write a converter class to just do "value.trim() return value"

Here is my xaml:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <!-- this is the actual grid column element binding -->
        <Condition Binding="{Binding FieldName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="SocketState"/>
        <!-- this checks the value on the element referenced ^here-->
        <Condition Binding="{Binding SocketState}" Value="Connected" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource YellowGreenGradientBrush}"/>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you first work out why your database values have developed trailing spaces, fix the root issue and cleanse the data?

Comment: Yeah, I agree. That's what I should/will do. But i'm not the only dev working on the code. I'll submit it to the fix list and my workaround will keep me from waiting on someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my issue by trimming in my sql view. No wpf code change necessary.